# Download the project from Trac?

Tags: trac

I want to download this project: http://trac.sitecore.net/AdvancedDatabaseCrawler/browser/Branches/v2/

How should I download the whole project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [go up a couple levels](http://trac.sitecore.net/AdvancedDatabaseCrawler/) (I just removed parts from the URL until it worked), you get this:

> The project code and documentation has been moved to the following location:
>
> [​https://github.com/sitecorian/SitecoreSearchContrib](https://github.com/sitecorian/SitecoreSearchContrib)
>
> The codebase will not be maintained here any longer.

So, go to the new URL on GitHub and grab the git URL (git://github.com/sitecorian/SitecoreSearchContrib.git), then either use `git`:

```
git clone git://github.com/sitecorian/SitecoreSearchContrib.git
```

Or paste the URL into [a git tool](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/).